# What is this pattern on this runway?

Tags: runways

What is this pattern on this runway? What is its function?

[image]

[Location on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B054'10.9%22N+117%C2%B043'51.6%22W/@36.0490836,-117.507017,357m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.9030167!4d-117.7309917)

Comment: To be honest, this device shown here is aviation-related (They use it to check the RCS of aircraft/aircraft parts), it is just not a runway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a runway that you see there. It is the US Navy's [Radar Cross Section Range](http://www.otherhand.org/home-page/area-51-and-other-strange-places/bluefire-main/bluefire/radar-ranges-of-the-mojave/junction-ranch-rcs-facility/) at Junction Ranch. From what I know, that is the platform on which they put the object which they want to see the Radar Cross Section of on. There is a radar at the other end of the "runway".

This is what it looks like:
[image]

[Image Source](http://thehowlandcompany.com/gallery/Junction_Ranch_RCS_Range.htm)

Comment: That's awesome, +1

Comment: NB: They do the same with ships. They circle in front of a coastal installation.

Comment: Interesting answer, but it doesn't seem to answer the question of `What is this pattern`. No downvote here, just saying.

Comment: Looking at the pattern, it appears to be markings on the surface of a turntable and the surrounding structure. The turntable is rotated maybe 55° clockwise from the surrounding structure. The three red lines are probably used to center the landing gear and orient the aircraft on the turntable.

Comment: @JonathanWalters The second sentence in the answer says, "It is the platform..." which does say what it is.